# Visual Studio Preview Data Unexpected Error

Tags: visual-studio

I am receiving the following error from VS2015.

I can connect to the database with the server explorer and retrieve data via server explorer. When I debug the program it retrieves the data as expected. I have tried re-installing Visual Studio (2015), MySQL for Visual Studio (1.2.6) and MySQL Connector(6.8.8).

[image]

Any ideas what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed MySQL connector and reinstalled Version 6.9.8 and it works fine now.